# Why is the length of the list displayed as zero in my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-ldap

```
import ldap

try:
    l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap.xxxxx.com:389")
    username=raw_input("Enter the username : ")
    password = raw_input("Enter the password :")
    if(username == "" or password==""):
        print "Login Error : Username or password can't be blank"    
    else:
        l.simple_bind(username,password)
        print "Contact..."

except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e

baseDn = "ou=active, ou=employees, ou=people, o=xxxxx.com";
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL
#retrieve all attributes
retrieveAttributes = None
search_query = raw_input("Enter the query :")
searchFilter = "cn="+search_query

try :
    ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDn, searchScope, searchFilter,   retrieveAttributes)
    result_set = []
    while 1:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
        if(result_data == []):
            break
        else:
            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                result_set.append(result_data)
            #print result_set

    print len(result_set)   

except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e

#print result_set[0]
```

The above code uses `python-ldap` to access ldap services. The `result_set` type is displayed as list but the number of items when using the `len()` function turns out to be zero. I need to perform operations on the retrieved string.

Comment: please fix the indentation

Comment: Perhaps put in a count to verify that you are picking up and appending the data when you think that you are appending. The while 1: does not read any data at all as the result_type is not indented.

Comment: I see that you fixed the indentation. Perhaps use a "print result_type" to verify that you are getting ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY so that the data is appended. print ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY gives a value of 100 (an int)

Comment: When I print "result_set" , the complete dataset is printed. However, I can't perform any operations on it. When I try to join the list to form a string , this error is thrown "{'info': '00002024: LdapErr: DSID-0C060598, comment: No other operations may be performed on the connection while a bind
 is outstanding., data 0, v1db1', 'desc': 'Server is busy'}"